# Kafka Connect gets fail after one of the broker node got down

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-compose, confluent-platform

I have a zookeeper , 2 cluster brokers and 2 cluster connects , Clustering connects work fine and completely cover each other. but when one of the broker node goes down then Connectors will print not connect to broker and connectors do not work correctly.
I checked connector topic and nothing push it after problem occurred.

```
version: '2'

volumes:
  zoo-data:
  zoo-log:
  broker-data:
  broker-log:  
  broker2-data: 
  broker2-log:  
  connecotr-data:
  connecotr2-data:  
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.2.0
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
      - "2888:2888"
      - "3888:3888"      
    volumes:
      - zoo-data:/var/lib/zookeeper/data
      - zoo-log:/var/lib/zookeeper/log
    environment:
#      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 22181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      KAFKA_OPTS: "-Dzookeeper.4lw.commands.whitelist=*"
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ZOOKEEPER_INIT_LIMIT: 5
      ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: 2

#      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: zookeeper:2888:3888      

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-server:6.2.0
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9101:9101"
    volumes:
      - broker-data:/var/lib/kafka/data
      - broker-log:/var/lib/kafka/log
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://:9092 
      DELETE_TOPIC_ENABLE: 'true'
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 2
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_LICENSE_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 2
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_BALANCER_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 2
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 2
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 2
      BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker2:29094,broker:29092
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      
  broker2:
    image: confluentinc/cp-server:6.2.0
    hostname: broker2
    container_name: broker2
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9094:9094"
      - "9103:9103"
    volumes:
      - broker2-data:/var/lib/kafka/data
      - broker2-log:/var/lib/kafka/log
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 2
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181      
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker2:29094,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9094
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker2:29094,PLAINTEXT_HOST://:9094         
      DELETE_TOPIC_ENABLE: 'true'
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 2
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_LICENSE_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 2
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_BALANCER_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 2
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 2
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 2
      BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker2:29094,broker:29092
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081

  #    BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker2:29094,broker:29092
  
  kafdrop:
    image: obsidiandynamics/kafdrop:latest
    container_name: kafdrop
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    environment:
      - KAFKA_BROKERCONNECT=broker:29092,broker2:29094
    depends_on: 
      - broker

  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:6.2.0
    hostname: schema-registry
    container_name: schema-registry
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092,broker2:29094'
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8081

  connect:
    image: cnfldemos/cp-server-connect-datagen:0.5.0-6.2.0
#    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:5.4.0
    hostname: connect
    container_name: connect
    depends_on:     
      - schema-registry
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092,broker2:29094'
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: connect
      CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: compose-connect-group
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-mysql
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_OFFSET_FLUSH_INTERVAL_MS: 10000
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-offsets
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-status
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: "org.apache.kafka.connect=DEBUG"
      # CLASSPATH required due to CC-2422
     # CLASSPATH: /usr/share/java/monitoring-interceptors/monitoring-interceptors-6.2.0.jar
   #   CONNECT_PRODUCER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringProducerInterceptor"
    #  CONNECT_CONSUMER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringConsumerInterceptor"
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: '/usr/share/java'
      CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: org.apache.zookeeper=ERROR,org.I0Itec.zkclient=ERROR,org.reflections=ERROR    
    volumes:
      - connecotr-data:/etc/docker/volumnes/kafka/connector/
            
  connect2:
    image: cnfldemos/cp-server-connect-datagen:0.5.0-6.2.0
#    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:5.4.0
    hostname: connect2
    container_name: connect2
    depends_on:     
      - schema-registry
    ports:
      - "18083:8083"
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker2:29094,broker:29092'
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: connect2
      CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: compose-connect-group
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-mysql
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_OFFSET_FLUSH_INTERVAL_MS: 10000
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-offsets
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-status
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: DEBUG
      # CLASSPATH required due to CC-2422
     # CLASSPATH: /usr/share/java/monitoring-interceptors/monitoring-interceptors-6.2.0.jar
   #   CONNECT_PRODUCER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringProducerInterceptor"
    #  CONNECT_CONSUMER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringConsumerInterceptor"
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: '/usr/share/java'
      CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: org.apache.zookeeper=ERROR,org.I0Itec.zkclient=ERROR,org.reflections=ERROR    
    volumes:
      - connecotr2-data:/etc/docker/volumnes/kafka/connector/
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your Connect topic replication factors are only one.

```
  CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-storage  # renamed - it is not only for mysql
  CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
  CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-offsets
  CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
  CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-status
  CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
```

If the broker hosting those topics crashes, then you should expect Connect to crash/stop working as well

Comment: thanks for answer. but my brokers is cluster and my connections is too. but one the my brokers crashed and another on is alive . In production, alive broker must handle this disaster and connections must push message to this broker automatically

Comment: I think you misunderstood my answer. If you have more than one broker, then you shouldn't have only one replica for these topics

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot.